# mysqlworkbench without root access

Tags: mysql, bash, diff, command-line-interface

I have a full normal user account for ssh access and I'd like to use the mysql diff capability of mysqlworkbench's mysqldbcompare (or some other cli tool if it exists). The problem is I don't have root access. Can I install this in my normal user account so I can compare my DB's on that server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do such things is to install them as root using the system's package manager, but I'm sure you know that :P

I downloaded the source code from [their website](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/), and it uses a traditional `configure` script. I have installed programs, in fact whole ecosystems, in unprivileged user accounts using `configure` scripts. Usually all it takes is to specify where you want files to be installed:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/eco
```

Sometimes you have to install dependencies too. Then make sure to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` accordingly.

Depending on the distro you're using, you can even install packages to your home directory: [see this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/23734/is-there-any-way-to-get-apt-to-install-packages-to-my-home-directory)

Comment: Thank you for including the answer to my next question also. :-)